# How to send data through email via phpmailer

Tags: php

```
<?php
      require 'mail/class.phpmailer.php';
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->Host = 'mail.cancerbengal.com';
      $mail->Port = 465;
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
     /*** various $var declarations removed as irrelevant **/ 
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
       /**various irrelevant code removed**/
       }
       $mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
       $mail->SingleTo = true; 
      $mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
      $mail->Body = "You have received a new message. ".$messageContents;
      $file_to_attach = 'photo';
      $mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , '$photo' );
      if(!$mail->Send())
                  {
                   echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " .$mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
                else
                 {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Registration is Successfull')</script>";
                }
```

This is `mail1.php` in the serve, the error is shown that `class.phmailer.php` could not open. How to solve that? Actually, I want to send a mail with two attachments but the attachments are not sent. Any help would be highly appreciated.the error is

**Error Output:**

> Warning: require(mail/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in /home/cancerbengal/public_html/mail1.php on
>   line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'mail/class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.: /usr/lib/php :
>   /usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cancerbengal/public_html/mail1.php on
>   line 2

Comment: Please supply the **actual error message** and line number, also indicate the line in your script

Comment: What is the path of `class.phpmailer.php`?

Comment: @Srrijita Daagupta Are you sure that class.phpmailer.php is inside mail folder?

Comment: yes the file is in mail folder

Comment: Warning: require(mail/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cancerbengal/public_html/mail1.php on line 2

Warning: require(mail/class.phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cancerbengal/public_html/mail1.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'mail/class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.: /usr/lib/php : /usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cancerbengal/public_html/mail1.php on line 2

Comment: seems your files includes path are wrong, where is phpmailer located ?

Comment: Use absolute path to access your class, not relative, so you can access it from anywhere: `require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/mail/class.phpmailer.php';`

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta, make sure about the structure. **mail** directory should be exists on same directory that contains `mail1.php`

Comment: no mail1.php is not in mail directory

Answer (score 0):

You really should update your PHPMailer script to use the newer PHPMailer and to use the **autoloader** . I highly recommend downloading the newest PHPMailer from github:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Now, your issue is that the file does not exist at the location specified,

the location you have specified on `require 'mail/class.phpmailer.php';`

```
<sourcefile>
     |
     |
     \-----> mail folder / class.phpmailer.php
```

This means that:

- You didn't upload the class file to the remote server.
- Your `<sourcefile>` is itself in a different/incorrect location
- If your `<sourcefile>` is `include`d elsewhere, in another script, then the includes within it are relative to *its own* location, rather than the location of it's 'parent' PHP file.

**Solution:**

Give an absolute value for the include path, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so:

```
require "mail/class.phpmailer.php";
```

becomes:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mail/class.phpmailer.php";
```

And this will work, no matter where your `<sourcefile>` is located.